# Is it possible to take a specific number of rows from certain column value, similar to a foreach loop in Java?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way to get behavior in kusto similar to a foreach loop in Java? For example, say I have a distinct list of services A-F, then for this distinct list, I want to take N rows for each distinct column value, is there a way to do this in a single query?

I have tried multiple ways of joining, but have not been able to get this to work in a dynamic way. What I mean by dynamic, is that I do not want to have to write different queries that specify `| where service = 'A' | take 30`.

```
ServiceLogs
| where isnotempty( service)
| distinct service
| join kind = rightouter ServiceLogs on $left.service== $right.service
| take 30
```

Actual results is that it only returns 30 for a single value in the distinct list not for each one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while there's no `foreach` operator, there are usually ways to achieve the goal using different functions/operators in the language.

In this specific case, it could be that using `top-nested` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/topnestedoperator) would help, or perhaps the `partition` operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/partitionoperator), depending on the amount of distinct values for `service`:

```
datatable(s:string, i:int, c:string)
[
    "a", 1, "not me",
    "b", 2, "not me",
    "c", 3, "not me",
    "d", 4, "not me",
    "a", 5, "me",
    "b", 6, "me too",
    "c", 7, "not three",
    "d", 8, "and me",
    "a", 9, "and me too",
    "b", 10, "count me in",
    "c", 11, "i",
    "d", 12, "myself",
]
| partition by s
(
    top 2 by i desc
)
```

Comment: I see that top-nested can simulate a foreach for producing aggregated values for each service, but would it be possible to extract sets of entire rows of data per service entry? So something similar to a result if I were to just query ServiceLogs | where service == 'A' | take 30 or ServiceLogs | where service == 'B' | take 30 and so forth foreach service?

Comment: if you have up to 64 distinct services, you could potentially use the `partition` operator (I've updated my reply)

Comment: Thank you, partition was what I was looking for.